# Getting error in the .print() of Flink in java in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime-error, apache-flink, flink-streaming

While trying to execute a basic Flink program in eclipse, I'm getting error due to .print() called by datastream_name.print() for printing my datastream.

*using Java8*

ERROR

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final byte[] java.lang.String.value accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @776aec5c
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:180)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:174)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:106)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:69)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2139)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.clean(DataStream.java:203)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.addSink(DataStream.java:1243)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.writeUsingOutputFormat(DataStream.java:1144)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.writeAsText(DataStream.java:1004)
    at orgname.testProjectFlink.App.main(App.java:19)
```

Comment: That stack trace is not from Java 8 as it includes the 'java.base' module - which means it is Java 9 or later. The InaccessibleObjectException is also Java 9 or later.

Comment: You are using either two java versions or `>11`

Answer (score 0):

What is the flink version?

Beginning from flink1.15, the support of Java 8 is now deprecated and removed (FLINK-25247). The Flink community recommends all users migrate to Java 11.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but except this particular function, everything else is working completely fine. So I guess version problem is not there. Is there anything else that I can do ?

Comment: @SakshiBhatia It is a version problem. The stack trace shows a modern version of Java which is not allowing Flink to mess around with the `String` class - that used to be possible but is no longer allowed.

Comment: Flink Java 8 support has not been removed yet, it has only been deprecated.

However, it does look like a mix-up of different Java versions. You should probably check that your IDE and compiled code are indeed all set to the same version. Also make sure that the Flink version you're using is indeed matching with that Java version (either Java 8 or Java 11). Other versions then Java 8 or 11 are not supported.